# Flutter Images Tags

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Does flutter have any package or plugin which lets us tap on the image and tag people or anything?
Basically, I want to take a pick of a few products and then tap on any particular image and then write the name of that product.
Help me out, guys

Comment: Depends on how you like to tag and share this info, a short way can be including map/list for each image, it will keep the tag users and if you wish to get the tap position use `GesterDetector's localPosition`

Comment: @arpit-jai did you get solution for same? plz let me know if you find any way OR plugin to achieve it because i have same requirement.